# Formation of α,β-unsaturated ketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, catalysis, reaction-control

In Claisen-Schmidt condensation I've used $\ce{NaOH}$ catalyst. Can I use $\ce{KOH}$ instead of $\ce{NaOH}$?

Answer (score 3):

In principle yes, though it depends on what solvent you are using. Its the OH which is important for the reaction not the counterion, though the counterion can affect the solubility.

Comment: Solvent is ethanol.

Comment: Then there should be no problem